# Unable to find request IP address when port forwarding

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

Unable to find request IP address when port forwarding

Example :

My Laptop Call > Jump Server Call >> The Web Server

At the Web Server the request ip will be every time the jump server ip

How to know the real ip that is call the Web Server in my case is My laptop not the Jump Server

Comment: When a reverse proxy nginx instance is used on the server you called the "jump server", it is possible to add this information via additional HTTP header like `X-Real-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For` (and extract this information later at the "web server" with the help of nginx [realip module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)). However I'm not sure this is possible at all using only the port forwarding.

Comment: what is an jump server?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the IP address

```
let ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

If your jump server acts as a proxy you might want to check to X-FORWARDED-FOR header.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For